# Symfony2 +Vagrant performance - running slow - speeding up?

Tags: performance, symfony, vagrant, assetic

I have started using vagrant with Symfony2.* to develop Web projects. I am using Windows, performance is very slow, because nfs mount isn't supported.

I've put cache into memory, which gave exotic boost, disabled xdebug (as posted [here](http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/08/19/speedup_symfony2_on_vagrant_boxes.html)). However page still loads in more than 14 seconds in dev enviroment on windows machines. Any help would be appreciated.

Symfony >=2.3, PHP >= 5.4, Windows 7, Dell Precission m6700 quad-core i7/16GB/SSD

Answer (score 9):

I've had the same performance problems, although with developing Drupal sites (also PHP based). Lately I've had quite some success by using the new [rsync folder feature](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/rsync.html), which was introduced in Vagrant 1.5.

If you're working with a large number of files (10.000 - 100.000), I experienced that the built-in rsync-auto feature had a hard time keeping up. Switching to [this neat little plugin](https://github.com/smerrill/vagrant-gatling-rsync) saved my day. Just as the vagrant rsync folder feature, the gatling rsync plugin also only provides a one way sync (host -> guest). Since a lot of Drupal tools and compass generate files on guest, [this plugin](https://github.com/smerrill/vagrant-rsync-back) will help to sync the changes from guest to host.

If you're looking for a comparison: [here you can find a recent benchmark blog post on rsync vs NFS](http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/nfs-rsync-and-shared-folder).

Comment: finally it works ! thank you Sidney

I had only one little issue. You need to publish assets in web folders (seems to has some issues with symlinks)

Comment: What type of issues Simone?

Answer (score 1):

- Under Windows you absolutely need to use **NFS** OR **RSYNC** for sharing
  folder with Vagrant.
- RSYNC is an good solution when automatic mode is activated but it's
  **not bidirectional**.

**Try this config.yaml** (make with PuPHPet): https://github.com/comexpertise/PuPHPet-config-lamp-webdev
Optimized for Windows: use NFS shares OR RSYNC.

**Very speed but not free**: Swith VirtualBox to VMWare with the Vagrant VMWare plugin (and use NFS or RSYNC sharing types).

**Another solution (best performances)**: need to disable Vagrant sharing folders for use local file system of VM, and configure your favorite IDE/FTP for use SFTP and simply upload modified files (Netbeans can automatically upload new created/modified files)

Edit: Read my comment #2 before about newest versions of Vagrant. You need more speed? Try VMware + Vagrant VMware plugin, it's the best (y)

Comment: You're right. Out-of-the-box, the Vagrant rsync feature is not bi-directional. I added some more information to my answer on how to achieve a bi-directional sync.

Comment: Yes :) But now, the new (native) sharing system included into newest versions of Vagrant is probably now the best solution (bi-directional and very speed) without additionals softwares/plugins required... Enjoy!

Comment: Well, I still think rsync is way faster than NFS, at least in working with large PHP frameworks such as Drupal. Recently Jeff Geerling benchmarked rsync vs NFS, where rsync is a clear winner: http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/nfs-rsync-and-shared-folder

Answer (score 0):

there is a great plugin enabling NFS on windows for Vagrant: vagrant-winnfsd

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd
```

https://github.com/GM-Alex/vagrant-winnfsd