# zend + vagrant page loading very slow

Tags: zend-framework2, vagrant

I have a massive web page on ZF2 and vagrant box as server.

Issue is it is very slow  the main page loads for 15+ sec.
Even the admin panel with loads with 2-4 sec delay on simple pages.

I did some debug end the index controller is called 2 sec after index.php
so i guess there is something wrong with the config / routing.
The sites uses several subdomain for each product.

Any ide/tool how to pin point the problem?

Comment: If you use `VirtualBox`, you can try to use `NFS` http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html. I use NFS/1 Gb memory/2 process core for VirtualBox

Comment: @newage I use Windows Host and they say NFS does not work on it.
The issue is the same for All OSs

Comment: You can try to increase memory and process core for VirtualBox

Comment: Take a look at some of my suggestions I gave in an answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983670/symfony2-vagrant-performance-running-slow-speeding-up/23983769#23983769 I think it could be of help to you

Comment: Did you fix this issues? I have the same problem

Comment: @MichałKalkowski the problem was in the complex architecture and mainly in the overusage of EventManager.