# Slow Symfony on vagrant box

Tags: symfony, vagrant

I'm on Windows 7 and i'm using vagrant box for a Symfony2 project.

I configured for nfs :

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 1234, guest: 80
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", type: "nfs"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 2048
    v.cpus = 2
  end
end
```

But my Symfony2 prokect is still veryyy slow.

What can i do ? I don't find a good solution...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2 +Vagrant performance - running slow - speeding up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983670/symfony2-vagrant-performance-running-slow-speeding-up)

Answer (score 4):

Overriding the `cacheDir` and `logDir` in `app/AppKernel.php` to a directory outside the NFS share usually gives quite a performance boost. For example:

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    return '/tmp/symfony/cache';
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    return '/tmp/symfony/logs';
}
```

Only con: you can't inspect the cache and log files from your Host system. This could also mean that you loose autocompletion in your IDE (eg. PHPStorm with Symfony2 Plugin).

Answer (score 2):

Try to move `vendor/` outside the shared directory.

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the methods for relocating the vendor folder worked for me in our project, I came up with this solution:

1. Enable symlinks for Virtualbox in Vagrant. (This feature is disabled by default for security reasons, so do this only on developer machines.) See: [Symbolic links and synced folders in Vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200333/symbolic-links-and-synced-folders-in-vagrant)

   ```
   config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
       vb.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root", "1"]
   end
   ```
2. Create the "var" and the "vendor" folders outside of the shared directory (usually "/vagrant"). (Don't forget setting the proper owner for these folders.)

   ```
   mkdir -p /var/cache/MyProject/var
   mkdir -p /var/cache/MyProject/vendor
   ```
3. Link them in the shared folder ("/vagrant"). (Delete the folders if they already exist.)

   ```
   ln -s /var/cache/MyProject/var /vagrant/var
   ln -s /var/cache/MyProject/vendor /vagrant/vendor
   ```
4. Execute the "composer install" only after the previous steps.

I got a 4-6 times speedup just because of the relocation.